# PE signature not found while Dotsfucating

Tags: .net, dotfuscator

I have a simple game that I'd like to dotfuscate. I've been using the free version bundled with Visual Studio and it have done a nice job so far. Until today when it seems to disassemble correctly but after that fails with the error message

```
Writing Assemblies...

PE Signature not found.  Is this a PE file?
Build Error.
```

Any clues to what night be wrong?

I've tried Building in different configurations, for different platforms and then I had a beer. None helped.

EDIT: I think it stopped working after upgrading to VS 2013 Update 4? That might just be a coincident though.

Comment: http://www.preemptive.com/contact/supportrequestform

Comment: thanks for the link but they don't provide support for the bundled version.

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I have the same problem.

Comment: Sadly no, I haven't tried it in quite a while now anyhow. Perhaps they updated version they ship with Update 3 of Visual Studio fixes this issue.